# Ghostscript is not building libgs on Mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, ghostscript

I would like to install libspectre.  It requires libgs. I have downloaded ghostscript 9.10 from ghostscript.com. It compiles and builds, but does not build libgs.  I have looked carefully at the configure options, but nothing speaks to why libgs is not being built. I am running OS X Mavericks with XCode 5.1.1.  Ghostscript installs a bunch of stuff in /usr/local/share and /usr/local/bin, but no includes or libraries. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it to build a dynamic library, or shared object in Linux terms. So 'make so'

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I had tried 'shared' and 'dynamic" but never thought of 'so' I come from a Unix (Solaris) background, but the only shared libraries I have built for years have suffixes of '.dll' and '.dylib'. It is pretty well hidden in the documentation. I think it should be a 'configure' option, like it is in most open source.